# Redhat 5.5: Multi-thread process only uses 1 CPU of the available 8

Tags: linux, redhat, task-scheduler, threads

Weird situation:
Redhat Enterprise 5.5 (stock install, no updates, x64) on a HP z800 workstation.
(Dual Xeon 2,2 Ghz. 8 cores, 16 if you count Hyper-threading. RH sees 16 cores.)

We have an application that can utilize 1, 2 or 4 threads for heavy calculations.
Somehow all these threads run on the same core at 100% load (the other 15 cores are nearly idle) so there is absolutely no benefit from the extra threads.
In fact there is a slight slowdown as the threads get in each others way on the single core.

How do I get them to run on separate cores (if possible)? Application is 64 bit. Can't change anything about the software except changing the threads setting.
Is there some obscure Linux setting I can try to change? (I'm a True64 and Aix guy. I use Linux, but have no in depth knowledge of the process scheduling on Linux.)

---

/proc/cpuinfo list al 16. top en gnome cpu-monitor both indicate only 1 core is used. I tried something similar to that perl thing as well. We can load all CPU to nearly 100% if we want to.
Application vendor claims: Yes it is multi-threaded but it is not optimized yet. That will be the next version (in August).

So I think the application is doing sub-threading within it's own process-space in stead of proper real separate process threads. Really nothing I can do about it then....

Comment: what's the application?

Comment: what kind of app? is it java, if so, does it use green or native threads?

Comment: You should verify with `htop` or a similar tool, that the application is actually using several threads actively - or just one.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [stress utility from RPMforge](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/rpmforge-x86_64/stress-1.0.0-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm.html) or yum and run it with:

`stress --cpu 16` to generate 16 workers. As stated above, run `top` with the `1` switch to show all CPUs in the listing.

Once you've verified the CPU listing and activity, Ctrl-C out of stress and run your application. Start `top` with the same switch and then use the `H` switch to show all process threads.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure it's running on only one core? How did you check? top and then pressed "1" ? Do you see all your 16 cores on "top" after pressing "1"? Or in "cat /proc/cpuinfo" ?

What happens with other applications? If you start something like

```
perl -e 'foreach (1..9e9) { sqrt(1234) }' &
```

16 times, do you see in top all your 16 cores at 100% ?

I think this is more a configuration of your application and nothing specific to the linux system.

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo list al 16. top en gnome cpu-monitor both indicate only 1 core is used. I tried that perl thing as well. Pegs all 16 to nearly 100%.